# execute javascript from dom in ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have a page which loads it's content from ajax response. The problem is that ajax igonres all my scripts from the head tag in my html page. Is there any way to make those javascript files to execute in my ajax response?

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".all").click(function () {
        var all = $(this).attr("id");
        if (all != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/searchbrowselist.php",
                data: "all=" + all,
                async: true,
                success: function (option) {
                    var $this = $("#browsemusic")
                    $this.html(option);
                    $('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable({
                        connectWith: ".connected"
                    }).disableSelection();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
<?php
include ('dbcon.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['all']) && $_REQUEST['all'] != '') {

    // ===============================Button "ALL"====================================

    unset($_REQUEST['kw']);
    unset($_REQUEST['genre']);
    $query = "select * from music";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connected">';
    while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<li><div class="ui360"><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" >Add</button><a href="' . $info['path'] . '"> ' . $info['artist'] . ' - ' . $info['title'] . ' (' . $info['album'] . ') ' . '</a></div><hr /></li>';
    };
    echo '</ul>';
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['kw']) && $_REQUEST['kw'] != '') {

    // ============================= Search for music ================================

    $kws = $_REQUEST['kw'];
    $kws = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $kws);
    $query = "select * from music where title like '%" . $kws . "%' or artist like '%" . $kws . "%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connected">';
    while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<li><div class="ui360"><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" >Add</button><a href="' . $info['path'] . '"> ' . $info['artist'] . ' - ' . $info['title'] . ' (' . $info['album'] . ') ' . '</a></div><hr /></li>';
    };
    echo '</ul>';
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['genre']) && $_REQUEST['genre'] != '') {

    // =====================================Browse By Genre ===========================================

    $genre = $_REQUEST['genre'];
    $genre = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $genre);
    $gquery = "select music_id from musicgenre where genre_id = '$genre'";
    $results = mysqli_query($link, $gquery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $music = array();
    while ($id_result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $music[] = $id_result['music_id'];
    };
    echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connected">';
    foreach($music as $song) {
        $query = "select * from music where music_id = '$song'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());;
        while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<li><div class="ui360"><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" >Add</button><a href="' . $info['path'] . '"> ' . $info['artist'] . ' - ' . $info['title'] . ' (' . $info['album'] . ') ' . '</a></div><hr /></li>';
        };
    };
    echo '</ul>';
}
else {

    // ================================ Default =========================================

    $query = "select * from music";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo '<ul id="sortable1" class="connected">';
    while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<li><div class="ui360"><button type="button" class="addtoplaylist" >Add</button><a href="' . $info['path'] . '"> ' . $info['artist'] . ' - ' . $info['title'] . ' (' . $info['album'] . ') ' . '</a></div><hr /></li>';
    };
    echo '</ul>';
};
?>
```

html:

```
<div id="browsemusic">
    <?php include ( 'php/searchbrowselist.php'); ?>
</div>
```

so, the php file gets some values from ajax and loads the results in my div. I need it to also execute my scripts loaded in the head:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/berniecode-animator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/soundmanager2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/360player.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Add some code. Help us to help you.

Comment: added the code from my files

Comment: you usually don't 'execute' loaded scripts.  Consider them and their functions as inline with the rest of your loaded script.  Try writing a module or function that responds to the event you are delegating.